# Vue, composition: pass a "slot" prop as a an attribute value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-slot

In React is very easy, since there's no "slots". Everything are parameters. But I don't know how to pass a slot as a parameter. Here's what I did.

I created a new component, which uses the `v-menu` component from [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/):

```
// SelectorComponent.vue
<template>
  <v-menu>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <slot name="activator" v-on="on" />
    </template>
    ...
```

Then I used that component:

```
<Selector>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn text v-on="on">Type</v-btn>
  </template>
</Selector>
```

And when you presses the "Type" button, it doesn't show the menu. However, if I replace the slot by the button, it works:

```
// It works!
<template>
  <v-menu outlined :close-on-content-click="false" offset-y>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn text v-on="on">Type</v-btn>
    </template>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`scoped slots`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) by naming the slot `activator` and binding `on` attribute to `on` slot prop which could be drilled down to your custom component, inside it you receive that `on` as `<template v-slot:activator="{ on }">` :

```
/ SelectorComponent.vue
<template>
  <v-menu>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <slot name="activator" :on="on" />
    </template>
    ...
```

then use it like :

```
<Selector>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn text v-on="on">Type</v-btn>
  </template>
</Selector>
```